# Camel JdbcMessageIdRepository key insert after from route instead of onCompletion

Tags: apache-camel, idempotent

I am using Camel JdbcMessageIdRepository  to achieve the HA cluster but I am facing Issue with implementation.

**If key not found insert immediately instead of inserting the key Oncompletion route.**

Due to this issue files are processed twice.

Can someone please help, How to insert Key immediately if not FOUND?

Regards,
Sarada.

Comment: I think there is an eager option on the idempotent consumer EIP if you are using this. But your question needs a bit more detail to allow us to help you

Comment: @ClausIbsen JdbcMessageIdRepository works fine when referred at IdempotentConsumer but When added to the From route as Parameter it is tied up with life cycle and Insert only on OnCompletion. eager default value is true.

Answer (score 0):

I have extended the class JdbcMessageIdRepository and override the **queryforInt**

```
public class FuseJDBCMessageIdRepository extends JdbcMessageIdRepository {

    public FuseJDBCMessageIdRepository() {
    }

    public FuseJDBCMessageIdRepository(DataSource dataSource, String processorName) {
        super(dataSource, processorName);
    }

    public FuseJDBCMessageIdRepository(DataSource dataSource, TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate, String processorName) {
        super(dataSource, transactionTemplate, processorName);
    }

    public FuseJDBCMessageIdRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate, TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate) {
        super(jdbcTemplate, transactionTemplate);
    }

    @Override
    public int queryForInt(String key) {
        int value = super.queryForInt(key);

        if (value == 0 && insert(key) >0){
            return value;
        }
            return value;

    }

    @Override
    public int insert(String key) {
        return super.insert(key);
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(String key) {
        return super.delete(key);
    }
}
```